# Application works in VS, but fails once published

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have an application that runs perfectly when I run it from Visual Studio. But once I hit "Publish" and try to launch "setup.exe", I get an error message:

`This application could not be started. Do you want to view information about this issue?`

Clicking on yes leads me [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2715633?version=%28null%29&processName=myApp.exe&platform=0009&osver=5&isServer=0). I have no idea what "SHIM" is and it's definitely not part of the code.

The error is the same if I publish to a network share or to my local drive. Once installed, the application shows up in "Programs and Features" and can be uninstalled but a Start Menu entry is not added. It's as if the error occurs during the installation.

I tried chancing the prerequisites (and target framework) between 3.5 and 4, as well as Windows Installer 3.1 vs 4.5 - no dice.

While it is currently targetting 3.5, it was originally created as a 4.03 app. I did change the target framework a couple times and going back to 4.03 doesn't fix it. I'm pretty sure this issue appeared as a result of retargetting.

Can anyone provide clues where to look?

Comment: Are you targeting the correct version of .NET? On the user machine, I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a Look at configuration files if you have any `app.config` or `web.config`.

If you didn't find any tag regarding the target framework, Do a File Search on you solution folder and if you find something in `.csproj` or `.sln` files, change it to the correct one.

Comment: Well thanks. I decided to trust VS and deleted the Obj folder as well as my TemporaryKey file, my app.config file and my solution files. Then I loaded up the .csproj and rebuilt/published the thing again. It works. (?)

Comment: Changes in some files wouldn't be rolled back upon changing the target framework, that's the root cause. Good Luck bro